# How to include PHP error log in Plesk 10.4 control panel

Tags: php5, logging

We am using Plesk 10.4 for our production server.  I like to configure the PHP error logs in Plesk.  So that I can get my Php errors.

Any one please help me to add the PHP error logs to Plesk logs so that I can view from plesk control panel.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click your domain name, go to "PHP Settings", find there "error_reporting" option and set it to "E_ALL". All PHP errors will go to Apache error log then.

Comment: Do we have to do tis by loging in to Plesk as administrator?

Comment: Because I dont have an option to edit the error_reporting.

Comment: You may need Administrator privileges or you account has to be granted permission for PHP settings editing. If not granted, you will probably just see them read-only.

Comment: Hay thanks for your answer..  I will check it and let you know..